# Where does make defconfig get its configuration in OpenWrt?

Tags: kernel, make, openwrt

I am compiling an image for wifi devices using *OpenWrt*. Following the instruction I copy a simple `.config` file to TOP-DIR.

```
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx=y
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic=y
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_XXX_OpenWrt_Router=y
```

Then run the command `make menuconfig`. The outcome of this command is

```
.config file now having default configuration.
```

However, I don't know where all the new configuration comes from. If I just change `CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_XXX_Router=y` to `CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_YYY_Router=y` then the outcome of `make defconfig` must be a lot different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenWrt stores config in the directory

```
target/linux/<target system>/<subtarget>/profiles
```

You can set target system and subtarget with command `make menuconfig`:
[image: make menuconfig]

In my case:

target system = `ar71xx`

subtarget = `generic`

So the directory would be:

```
target/linux/ar71xx/generic/profiles
```

In this directory, you will find some predefine profiles, stores in `<profile>.mk` file. Those files define which packages will be used as default when a target profile is selected.

Answer (score 4):

The configs are generally stored in the directory

```
arch/$(ARCH)/configs
```

so that the default `x86` config is

```
arch/x86/configs/i386_defconfig
```

and the default `x86_64` config is

```
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```

where all paths are relative to the linux src root.

---

To find any default config for any arch, you can example the top level `Makefile` and find

```
include $(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile
export KBUILD_DEFCONFIG KBUILD_KCONFIG

config: scripts_basic outputmakefile FORCE
  $(Q)mkdir -p include/linux include/config
  $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=scripts/kconfig $@
```

and by examining the Makefile at `$(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile`, eg `arch/x86/Makefile` you will find:

```
ifeq ($(ARCH),x86)
  ifeq ($(shell uname -m),x86_64)
        KBUILD_DEFCONFIG := x86_64_defconfig
  else
        KBUILD_DEFCONFIG := i386_defconfig
  endif
else
        KBUILD_DEFCONFIG := $(ARCH)_defconfig
endif
```

where the final result of the variable `KBUILD_DEFCONFIG` contains the filename of the default config for the architecture.

Comment: Thanks @casey. However the openwrt structure is quite different [Makefile](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/Makefile). It does not contain KBUILD_DEFCONFIG.

Answer (score 0):

All `CONFIG_` variables come from `openwrt/config`. There you can see all variable that located in `openwrt/.config` file. For examples `CONFIG_DEBUG` is located in `openwrt/config/Config-build.in` as

```
config DEBUG
    bool
    prompt "Compile packages with debugging info"
    default n
    help
      Adds -g3 to the CFLAGS.
```

Also you can define your variables in that file too.